# How to use mix function in laravel

Tags: css, laravel, versioning, laravel-mix

I'm writing a program using laravel. To manage css and js, I used versioning and call it with a function like this 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}">` 
The code above produces html output as follows 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css?id=53a226b301fc510ddf79">`


When I upload to hosting, why does the above code only produce html like this ? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">` (the mix-manifest.json / id file not load)

this is my localhost
[image]

and this is on the hosting
[image]

Comment: could you please show your `webpack.mix.js`? also your Laravel version?

Comment: mix.version();
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    // .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [

        require("tailwindcss"),
       ]);


I use laravel 8.4

Comment: Which hosting environment are you using? I'm assuming you upload the source code to a repo and it builds from that, rather than uploading the files you complied locally.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `npm run dev` after deploy it on your hosting?
Make sure in your `webpack.mix.js` have `.version()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your localhost your laravel run in `development` mode. And in the hosting the laravel run with `production` mode. Check your `.env` file.

Comment: Yes. On localhost, the env value is local. When I change the env value to production, the versioning doesn't run. Then, does the env value on the hosting have to be local?

Comment: Yes. If you want to the versioning run, the env value on the hosting have to be local. Because in `local` browser will not cache js file.

Comment: In production, Js caching is important, It will affect the speed of the website